# keyup() bug in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

```
 $('input').keyup(function(e){
  var k = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;          
  console.log(k);  

  });
```

.

```
    <input type="text" name=""  autocomplete="off"/>
```

Why keyup fires twice but only after second strike for special keys (arrows, space, backspace etc) ? 
-  Are any solutions  to fix this issue?
- the autocomplete it's turned off
-  In IE it is working fine
-  With keydown or keypress is working fine for FF and Chrome
-  But I can't use keypress because it doesn't work for IE for special keys
-  I can't use keydown because I need the value of the input including the character I just type. Like this `$(this).val();` - (I needed it for a live search). Keydown will give the value but without the last char. Maybe you could give me an idea in this direction - how to capture the value including last char with keydown?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Just what exactly are you trying to do? How is space a "special key"? IE fires a `keypress` just fine when the user presses space, and `keyup` will only ever fire once when a key is released.

Comment: yes keyup  fires once except for arrows, backspace, space, pgDown etc. But it has this problem only in FF and Chrome.
this time use the console and you will see that first time you push an arrow it will give you no result and at the second strike for example for left it will return twice 37.

Comment: yes keypress works fine in IE except for arrows and few other keys. Replace the console with an alert and try to run it in IE, you will see that it will not return nothing for arrows or backspace

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm saying that only one `keyup` event is fired for any key in Firefox or Chrome, and if you're seeing two then you must have an error in your code.

Comment: also keypress doesn't fire notjing for arrows,delete, insert etc neither in Chrome

Comment: For TIM: with the above code, for you, in FF, when you press one time right arrow, you see an 39 in console? Try it many times with other keys also, and alternate them.

Comment: I've tried it again, and I still get the expected behaviour, which is a single entry in the console for each and every key release.

Comment: That it weird because I tried with other keyboard and the same problem. Maybe we use different version of browsers. I use FF 3.6 and Chrome 4.0, and the the latest version of jquery. If you use the same browser and you used the exact code that it is above, I really don't understand why are this differences. The OS could make the diference?

Comment: Perhaps you post the whole code for your page (or a link to it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I'm a bit confused, will combining keyup and .val() not do what you want?

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
  liveSearchFunction($(this).val());
});
```

If not please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Yes keyup will give the value that i need (including last char). But when I try to navigate on the result list with up and down arrows, or I press backspace, first stroke will not do nothing and the second stroke will fire twice. (so basically it jumps over one result). Put my code and watch closely for the console result when you push arrows or backspace, enter etc